# How i can use one adapter for few fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

There are several fragments. In each of the fragment i have recyclerView with adapte). At the time when i create 3rd adapter I understood that in principle they are similar in their structure(ImageView, textView, textView), only arrays in which I keep the text and pictures are different. Well, actually I suggested an idea as possible, and most importantly whether to use one adapter for all my fragments? At the moment, my adapter:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] titles = {"Chapter One",
        "Chapter Two",
        "Chapter Three",
        "Chapter Four",
        "Chapter Five",
        "Chapter Six",
        "Chapter Seven",
        "Chapter Eight"};

private String[] details = {"Item one details",
        "Item two details", "Item three details",
        "Item four details", "Item file details",
        "Item six details", "Item seven details",
        "Item eight details"};

private int[] images = { R.drawable.android_image_1,
        R.drawable.android_image_2,
        R.drawable.android_image_3,
        R.drawable.android_image_4,
        R.drawable.android_image_5,
        R.drawable.android_image_6,
        R.drawable.android_image_7,
        R.drawable.android_image_8 };

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public int currentItem;
    public ImageView itemImage;
    public TextView itemTitle;
    public TextView itemDetail;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        itemTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        itemDetail =
                (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on item " + position,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
    viewHolder.itemDetail.setText(details[i]);
    viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titles.length;
}
```

}

Comment: convert int to string

Comment: Share code of TextNumeric.

Comment: what is TextNumeric ?

Comment: My guess is that `object.getType()` returns a `String`.

Comment: Yes, object.getType() returns a String, but how i can fix that problem in method onBindViewHolder?

Comment: @VadimMorozov Is your problem solved ??

Comment: @sushildlh yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check object.getType()  what is it returning. The issue is related to this. I am sure it is returning string. That is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this because from your question it seems you are getting integer but String is expected

```
case TYPE_TEXTVIEW:
                ((NumericViewHolder) holder).title.setText(String.valueOf(object.getTitle()));
                break;

case TYPE_EDITVIEW:
                ((DropDownViewHolder) holder).title_options.setText(String.ValueOf(object.getTitle()));
                break;
```

Comment: I add +1)
But also AS excrete: TYPE_TEXTVIEW and TYPE_EDITVIEW

Answer (score 1):

just change your static variable types like:

```
public static final String TYPE_TEXTVIEW = "0";
public static final String TYPE_EDITVIEW = "1";
```

Hope it will help you out.